How to find the equation for $x_{\theta}$ in this problem?
I have the below problem from a research paper that I would like to solve
$$\frac{1}{2}(y^2 - \bar{y}^2) = -\gamma\sin\theta-\gamma_{\theta}\cos\theta + a_1 \tag1$$
where, $$a_1 = \gamma\sin\theta +\gamma_{\theta}\cos\theta$$ at $\theta=\bar{\theta}$. This gives me the following
$$y=[2(-\gamma\sin\theta-\gamma_{\theta}\cos\theta + \gamma\sin\bar\theta +\gamma_{\bar\theta}\cos\bar\theta) + \bar{y}^2]^{1/2}$$ Here, $\bar{y}$ is the value of $y$ at some angle
$\theta = \bar{\theta} \tag2$.
Now, there are further couple of equations,
$$yy_{\theta} = - (\gamma + \gamma_{\theta\theta})\cos\theta \tag3$$ and
$$yx_{\theta} = (\gamma + \gamma_{\theta\theta})\sin\theta \tag4$$
Where, $$\gamma(\theta) = 1+\gamma_{d}\cos[4(\theta+\theta_{0})]$$ Here, $\gamma_{d}$ is a constant, and $\theta_{0}$ is some phase angle. I have to substitute the above equation and it gives me:
$$yx_{\theta} = \gamma\sin\theta-16\gamma_{d}\cos[4(\theta + \theta_0)]$$
Now, after substituting $y$ from equation(2) into equation(4) I need to find an equation for $x_{\theta}$ such that can be integrated numerically. Here, subscripts denote differentiation, so $\gamma_{\theta\theta}$ is double derivate of $\gamma(\theta)$ w.r.t $\theta$, and similar for $x_{\theta}$.
Can anyone suggest how to proceed forward and then obtain the equation for $x_{\theta}$? I'm stuck at what to do with $\bar{y}$, how should I eliminate it. The paper doesn't state the final equation for $x_\theta$, and hence I'm here for a solution. Any suggestions or help appreciated.

Source for the paper: here, the problem stated is from equations 2.7, 2.6 and 1.5 in the article.

In my experience, most people here will like to see a reference to this research paper (to see the context).

@JosBergervoet DOI added

We have
$$\gamma= 1+\gamma_{d}\cos(4\theta+4\theta_{0})$$
$$\gamma_{\theta}=-4\gamma_d\sin(4\theta+4\theta_0)$$
$$\gamma_{\theta\theta}=-16\gamma_d\cos(4\theta+4\theta_0)$$
So, we get
$$\frac{1}{2}(y^2 - \bar{y}^2) = -\sin\theta-\gamma_{d}\sin\theta\cos(4\theta+4\theta_{0})+4\gamma_d\cos\theta\sin(4\theta+4\theta_0) +\sin\bar{\theta}+\gamma_{d}\sin\bar{\theta}\cos(4\bar{\theta}+4\theta_{0})-4\gamma_d\cos\bar{\theta}\sin(4\bar{\theta}+4\theta_0)\tag1$$
$$yy_{\theta} =-\cos\theta + 15\gamma_d\cos\theta\cos(4\theta+4\theta_0)\tag2$$
and
$$yx_{\theta} =\sin\theta-15\gamma_d\sin\theta\cos(4\theta+4\theta_0)\tag3$$
It follows from $(2)(3)$ that
$$yy_{\theta}\sin\theta+yx_{\theta}\cos\theta=0$$
Dividing the both sides by $y\ (\not=0)$, we get
$$y_{\theta}\sin\theta+x_{\theta}\cos\theta=0$$
which implies
$$x_{\theta}=-y_{\theta}\tan\theta\tag4$$
which might be useful.

Thanks for providing this approach, although I'm not sure that $x_\theta$ will be integrable, may be one can use this $yy_\theta = -(\gamma_\theta + \gamma_{\theta\theta})\cos\theta $ which I didnt provide in my question to further reduce it.

@newstudent : I thought $\gamma_{\theta\theta}=\gamma_{\theta}=\gamma(\theta)$ (I thought $\gamma_{\theta\theta}$ is just a typo). However, from what you've written, maybe I am wrong. If it is wrong that $\gamma_{\theta\theta}=\gamma_{\theta}=\gamma(\theta)$, then what is $\gamma_{\theta\theta}$ ? Also, do we have $\gamma_{\theta}=\gamma(\theta)$ ?

acc. to the paper, subscripts denote differentiation, and $\gamma_{\theta\theta}$ is double derivative of $\gamma$ w.r.t $\theta$, and same for $x_\theta$ etc.. I think I should add these in the question.

@newstudent : Thanks. I rewrote the answer. I got $x_{\theta}=-y_{\theta}\tan\theta$ which might be useful. I'll keep thinking about it.

Thanks, but  in your solution, it looks like you have used eqs 2 and 3 to get $x_\theta = -y_\theta\tan\theta$ which is not I wanted. The derivation needs to substitute the value of $y$ from $\frac{1}{2}(y^2-\bar{y^2}..)$ equation into eq(3) to obtain $x_\theta$
